# Making an offhand note in a citation

Tags: citations, citation-style

I noticed that a PDF link from a university course I used as a URL to cite doesn't open, unless it's opened from the course portal itself. Within my referencing of the source, I note which link to click to find the correct PDF, and the URL I use is the course portal where the link is.

However, I've never given instructions on how to open a PDF from the right website before *within* a citation itself, let alone make any kind of offhand note in a citation before. Is it bad prose to do this, and instead just link the course portal URL? If not, how am I meant to properly cite this?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but a lot of links on news aggregation sites back to the original articles will be marked (paywalled) to indicate that clicking might not work for a given user. What you suggest isn't far off from that.

Comment: Can you craft a URL that opens the PDF?